Why do my styles from Bootstrap dictionary not work?
I have problem with my project which use styles from Bootstrap.
Here is the part of the code from package.json:
  "bootstrap": "^5.3.3",

and below is code from angular.json:
    "styles": [
      "src/styles.css",
      "node_modules/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css"
    ],
    "scripts": [
      "node_modules/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js"
    ]

I tried to implement and reinstall my Bootstrap dictionary.

You might want to be more specific on the part of your code you are having difficult with. SO provides us with a good guide as to how to ask questions with a better chance to get the help you are after.
